# jQuery template, invoke owne function inside each

Tags: jquery-templates

is this possible to invoke function inside each.

I've array of objects:

```
 Object { 
    array = new Array(), //{ true, true, false }
    areAllTrue = function(){
    //check if true code
    }
 }
```

I need to invoke this in:

```
{{each Array}}
  ${$value.areAllTrue()} 
{{/each}}
```

and it works for only last object.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit vague of what you're actually trying to do since none of the code are syntatically correct. I can only guess what you meant using below code.

```
//you have an array of objects, where each has a function
var objArray = [
  {
    objFunc: function(){
      return 'objArray #0 objFunc';
    }
  },
  {
    objFunc: function(){
      return 'objArray #1 objFunc';
    }
  },
  {
    objFunc: function(){
      return 'objArray #2 objFunc';
    }
  }
];

//you need to call each function of all objects
//in the array via jQuery "each" method.
$.each(objArray,
  function(idx, itm){
    //"itm" is the array item, which is the object
    var a = itm.objFunc(); //call it
    //log the result. see web browser Console
    console.log(a);
  }
);
```

Comment: OK, everything is clear. I am getting this from JSON after that all objects of my type was converting to Object type and then I was adding new object of my type.